# Why are POST requests to get a bearer token for application-only auth for Twitter's API returning a 400 Bad request?

Tags: curl, twitter, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to follow the instructions for obtaining a bearer token for the Twitter API's app-only authentication, following the instructions here:

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

However, every time I make the request described there with curl, I get a "400 Bad request" status returned and an empty response body.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I'm trying this with `curl` thinking that that will make it easier to make the right request. First:

```
$ export CONSUMER_KEY="[...]"
$ export CONSUMER_SECRET="[...]"
```

Obviously I've elided the values there, but those are the ones I've got from https://apps.twitter.com/ on the "Keys and Access Tokens" tab for the an app I created - they're from the two redacted parts here:

[image: redacted screenshot of apps.twitter.com ID keys and access tokens tab]

Then I'm making the request with:

```
curl --trace-ascii curl-trace \
    -X POST \
    --data 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" \
    -H "User-Agent: YNR Twitter ID mapper v0.0.1" \
    -H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n "$CONSUMER_KEY:$CONSUMER_SECRET" | base64)" \
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'
```

However this consistently returns a 400 Bad request and empty body, even though what's being sent to the server looks exactly what's required by the documentation.  To show this, the relevant output from the `curl-trace` file from the command is:

```
== Info: Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
== Info:   Trying 104.244.42.194...
== Info: Connected to api.twitter.com (104.244.42.194) port 443 (#0)
[... elided SSL connection details ...]
0000: POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
001d: Host: api.twitter.com
0034: Accept: */*
0041: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
0080: User-Agent: YNR Twitter ID mapper v0.0.1
00aa: Authorization: Basic [...]
00ea: [...]
012a: Content-Length: 29
013e: 
=> Send data, 29 bytes (0x1d)
0000: grant_type=client_credentials
== Info: upload completely sent off: 29 out of 29 bytes
== Info: HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
<= Recv header, 26 bytes (0x1a)
0000: HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
<= Recv header, 19 bytes (0x13)
0000: content-length: 0
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: date: Sun, 24 Apr 2016 12:55:59 GMT
<= Recv header, 15 bytes (0xf)
0000: server: tsa_f
<= Recv header, 53 bytes (0x35)
0000: x-connection-hash: [...]
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
== Info: Closing connection 0
== Info: SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
=> Send SSL data, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: ..
```

I'm baffled by why this isn't working!

Answer (score 6):

(OK, as often happens I worked out what was wrong before posting the question, but the answer might be helpful to some other people, so I'll just post it here anyway.)

What [the Twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) are describing, in the part where you base64-encode `$CONSUMER_KEY:$CONSUMER_SECRET` and sending it in the `Authorization` header, is just [HTTP basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

As that Wikipedia page says, though:

> The resulting string is encoded using the RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64, **except not limited to 76 char/line.**

(my emphasis). When I was constructing the string with:

```
echo -n "$CONSUMER_KEY:$CONSUMER_SECRET" | base64
```

... that included a newline (`0a`) in the output to break the long line, which, as that quote explains, you don't want when encoding the string for HTTP basic access authentication. You can suppress the line wrapping with `-w 0` like this:

```
echo -n "$CONSUMER_KEY:$CONSUMER_SECRET" | base64 -w 0
```

So the working version of the command I tried is:

```
curl --trace-ascii curl-trace \
    -X POST \
    --data 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" \
    -H "User-Agent: YNR Twitter ID mapper v0.0.1" \
    -H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n "$CONSUMER_KEY:$CONSUMER_SECRET" | base64 -w 0)" \
    --compressed \
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'
```

#### Much simpler version

It's easier to just get `curl` to do the HTTP basic authentication for you with its `-u` option, rather than mess around with `base64` yourself. The simplest version of the `curl` command that works for me is:

```
curl -u "$CONSUMER_KEY:$CONSUMER_SECRET" \
    --compressed \
    --data 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'
```

(Thanks to the comment of [Hans Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3748349/hans-z) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27631636/223092) which got me on the right track here!)

Comment: Thanks for examples. I had error #99 because of incorrectly formed basic auth header -- spotted difference by comparing my debug with `curl -v -u`